# Get all text of specific style from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a JtextPane that has `style1`, `style2` etc. I want to retrieve all text that is in the textPane that has been inserted with `style1`.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT** What I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a client that receives different `MessageTypes` from the server. I have a "debugging" window that logs each message to the JTextPane. The window has a set of JRadioButtons corresponding to each type of message. The user can check off the buttons to see specific types of messages that were sent from the server.

Comment: if style1, 2, etc are attributes it should be simple to loop through all your JTextPane objects and only pick up the messages from the JTextPanes that have that attribute, right?

Comment: Not sure how I would loop over the JTextPane. I could iterate through each character and call `getAttributes()` on that character, but that returns an AttributeSet. How would I go from AttributeSet to `Style`

Comment: can you post code where you set the style? And you may have to build a method that 'loops' through each JTextPane by checking them each individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own attribute and place it with all the other ones. Just use `SimpleAttributeSet` and place there the new attribute (let's name it "MessageTypeAttribute") the value could be string constants for each required type.

To iterate the `Document` use `getCharacterElement()` method. Start from 0 and then move to the end offset of the element to retrieve the next one.

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html), you can call getStyle( String stylename ) to get the style of a JTextPane.

You may want to build a method like this to select the text you want

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllOfOneStyle( String inStyle ){
   ArrayList<String> strAL = new ArrayList<String>(); 
   if( jtextpane_01.getStyle(inStyle) != null ){
      strAL.add( jtextpane_01.getText() );
   }

   // do this for each JTextPane

}
```